# Multiple Find & Replace

Tags: excel, vba, search, replace, find

I've trawled this site but not found anything exact for my issue.

I have an excel file (Sheet1) containing various foreign characters (eg. "ä" or "Ö") within multiple columns and rows (basically the entire sheet).

In Sheet2 I have a list/table (Columns A & B) of these characters (A) and what they need to be replaced with (B).

I would like a VBA code to search for all of these characters in Sheet1 and replace them all with the corresponding alternative.

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks,

Comment: what all have you tried please include in question?

Comment: Use a simple loop through your list in sheet2 and utilize the `Range.Replace` method. Also, these things *have* been done before and are to be found on SO I'm sure. They revolve around [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/707-excel-replace-accented-characters.html) function.

Comment: I have no VBA experience and hoped this may solve my issue. I have this problem often and normally manually check cell by cell and over type which takes hours!

Comment: I found a few solutions on here but they don't work for my parameters and probably linking to the wring cells, sheets or data.

Comment: Well, instead of cell-by-cell, you can find > Replace > All....if you do this manually. If you plan on using VBA, are you expecting others to write it for you? Or do you have some code?

Comment: I've tried a basic substitute string but I have like 89 characters so this becomes too long.

Comment: Try looping through Sheet2, columns A&B. For each pair of the original character (`strChar`) & desired replacement (`strRepl`) you can then do `Sheet1.UsedRange.Replace What:=strChar, Replacement:=strRepl`

Comment: Sorry I thought that's what this site is for. I presumed it may already be available. I have found similar solutions but not quite exact so they don't work. Not to worry.

Comment: Hi Ross, SO is actually trying to help users with their existing solutions and tries to develop/improve their skills. Please edit your question to show us your approach (even the most basic, failed one), so that we can develop it together. You will benefit from it greatly as it will get you started with VBA and you will understand the code. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Thanks Justyna. I have tried a few. Such as:

Sub Test()

    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
   
    Set Sh1 = Sheets(1)
    Set Sh2 = Sheets(2)
    For Each cel In Sh2.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)  'Text to find
        With Sh1.Cells   'Text to search
            Set c = .Find(cel, lookat:=xlPart)
            Do
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    c.Value = Replace(c, cel, cel.Offset(, 1))
                End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop Until c Is Nothing
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Ross, best is to update your question with your attempt so that people that visit this page won't have to find this information in a comment.

Comment: Hey Ross, you almost got it! You can either use Dave's solution (posted below), or use your own code that I will adjust in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Ross, your solution almost did the trick. You can simplify it by using:

```
Sub ReplaceChar()
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range

    Set Sh1 = Sheets(1)
    Set Sh2 = Sheets(2)

    For Each cel In Sh2.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
        With Sh1.Cells
            .Replace What:=cel, Replacement:=cel.Offset(, 1), MatchCase:=True
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Sheet1 and Sheet2 before running the macro:

[image]

[image]

...and here's Sheet1 after running the code:

[image]

Comment: Almost there, I would suggest including a `MatchCase` to distinguish between upper and lowercase =)

Comment: Then, if I would be nitpicking (I know, can be anoying), best is to iterate through memory, capturing sheet 2's values in a 2d-array. Nonetheless, good job, I can't upvote twice

Answer (score 0):

Experience has shown me that upper & lower case chars are treated the same when using find and replace.

The below sample uses column Q as the character to find and column R as the replacement. The code does the find replace for cells in column A

```
Sub Using_Replace()
    Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("Q1:Q" & LstRw)

    For Each c In rng.Cells

        Range("A:A").Replace what:=c, Replacement:=c.Offset(, 1), _
                             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                             SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next c

End Sub
```

---

[image]

When you test out the code you will notice the find/replace does not notice the difference between the characters in Q6 & Q15.

But if you loop through each cell, the differences are recognized.

-

```
Sub Using_LikeLoop()
    Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim frNg As Range, f As Range

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("Q1:Q" & LstRw)
    Set frNg = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each c In rng.Cells

        For Each f In frNg.Cells

            If f Like "*" & c & "*" Then f = Replace(f, c, c.Offset(, 1))

        Next f

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Dave, you are a gent and a genius!  This worked perfectly. Really appreciated.

Comment: The solution for distinguishing between upper- and lowercase is right in front of your eyes. `MatchCase:=False` > `MatchCase:=True`, and that would eliminate the need to iterate over all cells =)

Comment: Thanks also to JvdV and Justyna. You are life savers. Well a huge amount of time savers. Thanks so much guys.

Comment: Why have you not picked this as an answer? don't leave threads unanswered!